# Redshift SQL: swap and aggregate row to column

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Here's a table T1 in Redshift:

[image]

I am trying to create a query to represent it in the following manner:

[image: Transformed reporting layout]

What is the most optimal way to construct the query. The input table is created dynamically in another SQL query and the resultset of that query will not be small - like 400 to 500 rows / 3 columns.

Greatly appreciate any hints, suggestion, or solution to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select item,
       sum(case when period = 'Q1' then counts end) as Q1,
       sum(case when period = 'Q2' then counts end) as Q2,
       sum(case when period = 'Q3' then counts end) as Q3
from t
group by item;
```

If you want the row total, just add `sum(counts)` after `Q3`.

Comment: Gordon, Thx for the suggestion. I was not aware of this construct - very helpful. Two questions: I am getting an ERROR: invalid input syntax for type numeric: "Q1"; and secondly the table will be generated dynamically so I may not know ahead of time all the distinct values in Period column: Is it possible to dynamically detect them to use in the construct; something like looping through in SQL syntax?

Comment: Accept it because there was enough of a direction to take it to a complete solution. Fix to the query was to use period rather than -period, since  it was being compared to a string; also have to use both period and counts to the group by clause. I still like to see if we can handle dynamic list of values through SQL rather than a separate program. Thank you Gordon.

Comment: @user1931485 . . . The hyphen was a typo.  Cheers.